# Hahn–Banach, second geometric form, Why $\alpha$ can be > 0 in Corollary 1.8?

Tags: functional-analysis

- Corollary 1.8. Let $F \subset E$ be a linear subspace such that $\bar{F} \neq E$. Then there exists some $f \in E^{\star}, f \not \equiv 0$, such that
  $$
  \langle f, x\rangle=0 \quad \forall x \in F .
  $$
  Proof. Let $x_0 \in E$ with $x_0 \notin \bar{F}$. Using Theorem 1.7 with $A=\bar{F}$ and $B=\left\{x_0\right\}$, we find a closed hyperplane $[f=\alpha]$ that strictly separates $\bar{F}$ and $\left\{x_0\right\}$. Thus, we have
  $$
  \langle f, x\rangle<\alpha<\left\langle f, x_0\right\rangle \quad \forall x \in F .
  $$
  It follows that $\langle f, x\rangle=0 \quad \forall x \in F$, since $\lambda\langle f, x\rangle<\alpha$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I got it, because $x_0$ is chosen so that $f(x_0) > 0>f(x), \forall x \in F$ .